# spark: how to include dependencies with build/sbt compile

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am new to spark but am trying to do some development. I am following "Reducing Build Times" instructions from [the spark developer page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Useful+Developer+Tools#UsefulDeveloperTools-ReducingBuildTimes). After creating the normal assembly I have written some classes that are dependent on one specific jar. I test my package in the spark-shell in which I have been able to include my jar by using defining `SPARK_CLASSPATH`, but the problem lies in actually compiling my code. What I want to achieve is to include that jar when compiling my added package (with `build/sbt compile`). Could I do that by adding a path to my jar in `build/sbt` file or `sbt-launch-lib.bash`, and if so how?

(Side note:  I do not want to yet include the jar in the assembly because as I go I make some changes to it, and so it would be inconvenient. I am using Spark 1.4)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like what you are trying to do is compile your code into the Spark distribution that you are building.  Is that correct?  If so, that is definitely counter to normal practice.  You should be accessing your code the way you already are, by adding it to your CLASSPATH or by passing it into spark via spark-submit or the --jars argument when starting spark-shell or spark-submit.  You should leave the core Spark build alone unless you are modifying the core Spark libraries for a specific reason.

Comment: @DemetriKots Thank you for your reply! Yes, I have cloned spark and my eventual goal is to contribute to their libraries. I am adding a library to spark's mllib, and after setting 'export SPARK_PREPEND_CLASSES=true' I need to compile my code which depends on my local jar. Is there any way I can add that dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer in the comments above, it looks like you are trying to add your jar as a dependency to the the mllib project as you do development on mllib itself.  You can accomplish this by modifying the pom.xml file in the mllib directory within the Spark distribution.

You can find instructions on how to add a local file as a dependency here - http://blog.valdaris.com/post/custom-jar/. I haven't used this approach myself to including local file as a dependency, but I think it should work.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried the "Creating a maven repo inside the project" way and it worked well.